# How to change values in a list - python?

Tags: python, list

If I have a list like:

```
['15', 'A:B', 'B:C', 'D:C', 'F:A']
```

I want to change the values like:

```
['1515', 'A:B15', 'B:C15', 'D:C15', 'F:A15']
```

(add first one to other values in a list)

Is it possible?

Comment: What kind of data structure is that?...a list of what?

Comment: Do you have tried anything already with such a mysterious data?

Comment: srry :^( it was my mistake.

Comment: @dPdms okay, undeleted the answer as it fits the problem now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `["15", "A:B", "B:C", "D:C", "F:A"]` is your input list, a simple [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) would do the job:

```
>>> l = ["15", "A:B", "B:C", "D:C", "F:A"]
>>> value_to_add = l[0]
>>> [item + value_to_add for item in l]
['1515', 'A:B15', 'B:C15', 'D:C15', 'F:A15']
```